# Form to PHP, I need the contents of my form to be sent to my php and be displayed in a div styled on a new webpage

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I need the contents of my form to be sent to my php and be displayed in a div styled on a new webpage. Here's the code for the form.

```
<form name = "quoted" form action="genericwebpage.html" method="post">
<input id = "poster" type="text" name="poster" placeholder = "Credited Individual.">   <br>
<textarea class = "actual-quote" name = "actual-quote"placeholder = "Write the quote here!"></textarea><br><br>
 <input id = "submit1" type="submit">
</form>
```

and here's the php found on the webpage it's going to.

```
  <div class="wrapper">
<div class="submissions">
    <div class="logo-logo"><h2>Generic.</h2></div>
    <div class="top-submit"><?php echo $_GET['actual-quote']?></div>
    <div class="poster"><?php echo $_GET['poster']?></div>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me why it wont appear on my new webpage when I click the submit button?
Sorry, I am kind of a noob at this.

Comment: Those 2 are different files?

if yes.

save your 2nd code block to genericwebpage.php

and change your code inthe 1st block

    action="genericwebpage.html"

to

    action="genericwebpage.php"

Answer (score 0):

Using $_GET and $_POST is not the same thing. I have not test the script below. You might have to tweak abit

**If you want to use $_POST**

```
<form name = "quoted" method="post">
  <input id = "poster" type="text" name="poster" placeholder = "Credited Individual.">   <br>
  <textarea class = "actual-quote" name = "actual-quote"placeholder = "Write the quote here!"></textarea><br><br>
  <input id = "submit1" type="submit">
</form>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="submissions">
    <div class="logo-logo"><h2>Generic.</h2></div>
    <div class="top-submit"><?php echo $_POST['actual-quote']?></div>
    <div class="poster"><?php echo $_POST['poster']?></div>
</div>
```

**If you wan to use $_GET**

```
<form name = "quoted" method="get">
  <input id = "poster" type="text" name="poster" placeholder = "Credited Individual.">   <br>
  <textarea class = "actual-quote" name = "actual-quote"placeholder = "Write the quote here!"></textarea><br><br>
  <input id = "submit1" type="submit">
</form>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="submissions">
    <div class="logo-logo"><h2>Generic.</h2></div>
    <div class="top-submit"><?php echo $_GET['actual-quote']?></div>
    <div class="poster"><?php echo $_GET['poster']?></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Alright, so I have to use get instead of post, thanks for that, but it still doesnt show, and when I inspect element it shows the php commented out. <!--?php echo $_POST['actual-quote']?-->

Comment: thats because you are using php tags in html file. save your file as .php then it should work.

Comment: Ok thanks! so i just change the .html to .php and it should work?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the data by GET when you are actually sending it by POST. You should do something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="submissions">
    <div class="logo-logo"><h2>Generic.</h2></div>
    <div class="top-submit"><?php echo $_POST['actual-quote']?></div>
    <div class="poster"><?php echo $_POST['poster']?></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This one should be better if your form it not validated. Think if the user should fill all fields oblitagory.

```
<?php if (!empty($_POST['actual-quote']))echo $_POST['actual-quote']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Those 2 are different files? if yes.

save your 2nd code block to genericwebpage.php

and change your code in the 1st block

```
action="genericwebpage.html"
```

to

```
action="genericwebpage.php"
```

Comment: Ok, so how would I get the php to be displayed on the genericwebpage.html if its coming from a different original page? Sorry if I am confusing haha, thanks for the reply!

Comment: Ok now its showing this, any help? http://imgur.com/nXsetk8 thanks everyone for the responses so far, it's really helped!

Comment: you cannot display use php script in a html page. it will not work.

Change $_GET to $_POST

Answer (score 0):

On your form page, in the form code you have method="POST" but On your second page you have your 2 variables in `$_GET[]` change the `$_GET[]` on your second page to `$_POST` and you should be fine. Example below.

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="submissions">
 <div class="logo-logo"><h2>Generic.</h2></div>
 <div class="top-submit"><?php echo $_POST['actual-quote']?></div>
 <div class="poster"><?php echo $_POST['poster']?></div>
</div>
```